# How to use mutable references as arguments for generic functions in rust

Tags: algorithm, rust, pass-by-reference, strategy-pattern

I am attempting to practice using the stratergy pattern and thought to sort a vector using a function selected at runtime, ideally being able to change the data in place using a mutable reference.

I tried to add the keyword `&mut` in multiple places but could not figure out how to get my code to work with the mutable references.

Here is my code

```
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Sorter<F: Fn(Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>, T: Ord + Eq + Copy> {
    sort_strategy: F,
    sort_data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<F: Fn(Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>, T: Ord + Eq + Copy> Sorter<F, T> {
    // return self with sorted data
    // how do i remove the return self and make it a mutable reference to self
    pub fn sort(mut self) -> Self {
        self.sort_data = (self.sort_strategy)(self.sort_data);
        self
    }

    pub fn new(sort_strategy: F, sort_data: Vec<T>) -> Sorter<F, T> {
        Sorter {
            sort_strategy,
            sort_data,
        }
    }
}

// bubble sort function
pub fn bubble_sort<T: Eq + PartialOrd + Copy>(input_vector: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut output_vector = input_vector.clone();
    for _ in 0..output_vector.len() {
        for j in 0..(output_vector.len() - 1) {
            if output_vector[j] > output_vector[j + 1] {
                output_vector.swap(j + 1, j);
            }
        }
    }
    output_vector
}

// quick sort function
pub fn quick_sort<T: Eq + PartialOrd + Copy>(input_vector: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    if input_vector.len() <= 1 {
        return input_vector;
    }

    let pivot = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..input_vector.len());
    let pivot_val = input_vector[pivot];
    let mut little_vector: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    let mut big_vector: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    for i in input_vector.iter().enumerate() {
        if i.0 == pivot {
            continue;
        }
        if *(i.1) > pivot_val {
            big_vector.push(*(i.1));
            continue;
        }
        if *(i.1) <= pivot_val {
            little_vector.push(*(i.1))
        }
    }

    little_vector = quick_sort(little_vector);
    little_vector.push(pivot_val);
    quick_sort(big_vector)
        .iter()
        .for_each(|n| little_vector.push(*n));

    little_vector
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::vec;

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    // test that bubble_sort is functional
    fn test_bubble_sort() {
        let data = vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
        let result = bubble_sort(data);
        assert_eq!(result, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    }

    #[test]
    // test that quick_sort is functional
    fn test_quick_sort() {
        let data = vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
        let result = quick_sort(data);
        assert_eq!(result, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    }

    #[test]
    // test that bubble_sort works in struct Sorter
    fn test_stratergy_pattern_bubble() {
        let sorter = Sorter::new(bubble_sort, vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);
        let sorter = sorter.sort();
        assert_eq!(sorter.sort_data, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }

    #[test]
    // test that quick_sort works in struct Sorter
    fn test_stratergy_pattern_quick() {
        let sorter = Sorter::new(quick_sort, vec![5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);
        let sorter = sorter.sort();
        assert_eq!(sorter.sort_data, vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }
}
```

Or [on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bffd720880c4a316dfeca0ee57d27a44)

Comment: If my answer answers your question, you might want to consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, "remove the return self and make it a mutable reference to self" means we'd like `Sorter::sort()` to look like this:

```
pub fn sort(&mut self) {
    self.sort_data = (self.sort_strategy)(self.sort_data);
}
```

Doing that complains of not being able to move out of reference. The reason is that you cannot just take a value that resides in `self.sort_data` and pass it to a function that expects an owned value, such as `self.sort_strategy`. Doing that would leave `self` in a partially moved state - which the borrow checker supports, but then it won't allow further usage of the moved field, such as the assignment to `self.sort_data`.

If you don't want to change the signature of `sort_data`, then the easiest way is to *replace* `self.sort_data` with an empty vector, i.e. use `std::mem::replace(&mut self.sort_data, vec![])`. For types that implement `Default`, such as `Vec`, there is a `std::mem::take()` function that replaces with the default value. Then `sort()` would look like this:

```
pub fn sort(&mut self) {
    self.sort_data = (self.sort_strategy)(std::mem::take(&mut self.sort_data));
}
```

After trivial changes to the test suite not to capture the result of `sort`, your tests pass. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee9588f522ae97e817c63fab58af5ad3))

The next step is to be consistent and adjust the sort functions to also work in-place, i.e. change the bound from `Fn(Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>` to `Fn(&mut Vec<T>)` or, better yet, `Fn(&mut [T])` (because you don't need to grow or shrink the vector, you can sort the slice directly). In that case `Sorter` will look like this:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Sorter<F, T> {
    sort_strategy: F,
    sort_data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<F: Fn(&mut [T]), T: Ord + Eq> Sorter<F, T> {
    pub fn sort(&mut self) {
        (self.sort_strategy)(&mut self.sort_data);
    }

    // new is unchanged
}
```

Sorting functions like `bubble_sort()` no longer return a value, but just take `&mut [T]` and sort in-place instead of allocating - which is how sorting methods are [defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) in the standard library. In your case:

```
pub fn bubble_sort<T: Eq + Ord>(vector: &mut [T]) {
    for _ in 0..vector.len() {
        for j in 0..(vector.len() - 1) {
            if vector[j] > vector[j + 1] {
                vector.swap(j + 1, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=32005bce5c27b2b316e384a998546657)

(`quick_sort()` takes a bit more work to rewrite like this, so I skipped it.)

Side notes:

- you don't need `T: Copy`, swapping values works by moving.
- require `T: Ord` rather than `T: PartialOrd`, because sorts depend on total order, which is the guarantee provided by `Ord`.
- even in the design where the sorter takes and returns a `Vec`, a sorter like `bubble_sort()` naturally sorts in place. In that case it can work on the input vector and return it, there is no reason to clone it into an "output" vector.